# Getting data back from a Bootstrap modal

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I have a signup page that triggers a modal window (using [Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/javascript.html#modals)) containing for example a Facebook login and I want this modal to pass back data (errors, or if success the token / user data) to the main window so I can fill the relevant form fields and let the user complete the signup process (tick the "I approve the terms and conditions" box etc.).

I know how to do all of it except the bit about sending data back when the modal closes. Is there a way to pass data from the modal to the main window on the modal close event?

EDIT: here is a visual representation of what I want to accomplish:
[image: flow]

Comment: What do you mean by "sending back"? You are at the "main window" (the modal is just an element inside that) Why not assign values, error etc to hidden inputs or elements on the page itself?

Comment: The modal is actually calling a different URL where my auth controller is. So in the end I have a php array there and I want this to be used by the jquery script which will then assign the relevant values to the page. That's what I meant by "sent back": it's basically like an ajax call except the user has to interface with the modal window.

Comment: Something like http://sptalks.wordpress.com/2013/03/12/sharepoint-modal-dialog-passing-values-back-and-forth/ but with the Bootstrap modal if possible.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Well. You have access to both the main window and the modal content, so basically you just need to copy content from modal elements before closing. Working Example (copy the two codeblocks into two files) :

**auth.php** (dont know how your auth works, but perhaps you call a remote login and get some results, you can store in a JSON-array)

```
<label for="modal-username">Username</label><input type="text" name="modal-username" id="modal-username">
<?
$result = array();
$result['error']='error';
$result['auth']='auth';
$javascript_array = json_encode($result);
?>
<input type="hidden" id="modal-result" value='<? echo $javascript_array;?>'>
```

**modal.html**, main window

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<!-- button to trigger modal -->
<a href="auth.php" data-target="#myModal" data-toggle="modal">remote modal</a>

<!-- hidden fields to store modal result in -->
<input type="hidden" id="main-username">
<input type="hidden" id="main-result">

<!-- modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
    <h3 id="myModalLabel">Modal test</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Cancel</button>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="login();">Login</button>
  </div>
</div>​

<script type="text/javascript">
//called when user clicks login
function login() {
    $("#main-username").val($("#modal-username").val());
    $("#main-result").val($("#modal-result").val());
    $("#myModal").modal("hide");
}

//called when the modal is closed, logs values grabbed from the modal in login()
$('#myModal').on('hidden', function() {
    console.log('username : '+$("#main-username").val());
    console.log('result : '+$("#main-result").val());
})
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for taking the time to write such a detailed answer! It helped a lot.

Comment: Thanks, it was very helpful!

Comment: does not work  any  more 
with  hide  class  it  never  shown ,  replaced with style="display:none";

Comment: @Sergey It do work of course, but perhaps not with recent releases of bootstrap - which versions do you have in mind, particularly? Then I can make an update of the answer, _if_ you are right, and if it is nessecary.

Comment: i am using  the  last  one  of bs 3.
i'll try   to  update my  comment  tomorrow  with  more info .

Answer (score 8):

Bootstrap provides the following inbuilt event handling to achieve this:

**show.bs.modal**   - Occurs when the modal is about to be shown
**shown.bs.modal**  - Occurs when the modal is fully shown (after CSS transitions have completed)
**hide.bs.modal**   - Occurs when the modal is about to be hidden
**hidden.bs.modal** - Occurs when the modal is fully hidden (after CSS transitions have completed)

For your case you can use the hide.bs.modal event to get the values of the modal attributes after the button is clicked and before the modal is hidden. By this way the example given by davidkonrad can be achieved in a single function eliminating the need for intermediate hidden attributes.

```
    $('#myModal').on('hide.bs.modal', function () {    
    console.log('username : '+$("#modal-username").val());    
    console.log('result : '+$("#modal-result").val());    
})
```

Comment: Thank you! I had the same problem and I didn't know about these events!